# Duda con Flex en cabecera

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Buenas!,

Tengo una duda que no acabo de comprender. Estoy realizando una cabecera de una web, y me gustaría hacerla todo con flex. En este caso, he creado las cajas y las he aplicado inline-flex. El problema me surge, cuando quiero insertar una nueva caja con contenido dentro y me lo sigue alineando. ¿Como se puede evitar que siga alineando la caja que acabo de insertar en flex?

Pongo el código.

PD: He puesto el código completo.

```css
   /* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}

/* reglas generales */

a {
color: inherit;  /* ambos heredan del hereda del padre */
text-decoration: inherit; 
 }
 
 /* reglas tipograficas por defecto */ 
 
 body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-size: 1rem;
 line-height: 1.45;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
 color: #333;
 }
 
 h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 1.2rem;
 line-height: 1.2;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: steelblue;
 }
 
 * { padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
 
 /* IMAGENES  */

 img {width: 100%;}

/* BACKGROUND */

html {
background: url('img/fondo-dark.png');
}

body {
max-width: 93.75rem; /* ANCHO CENTRAL */
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: white;
}

/* HEADER *******************************************************************************************************************************************
*/

.header {
display: flex;
max-width: 100%;
height: 75rem;

background: url('img/dibujos/mujer-1600-1200-min.jpg') no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
}

.header-logo {
width: 6.25rem;
height: 5rem;
background: url('desarrollo/logo.svg') no-repeat center;
background-size: contain;
}

.logo a {
display: block;
height: inherit;
}

.header-container {
width: 100%;
height: 5rem;
display: inline-flex;
justify-content: flex-end;

margin: 1rem 1rem;
}

.header li {
padding-left: 1rem;
color: white;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Arial; 
font-weight: bold;
}

#item-lang-es {
padding-left: 2rem;
padding-right: 0;
}

#item-lang-en {
padding-left: 0rem;
padding-right: 0;
}

.header-menu-item  {
display: inline-flex;
}

.header-section {
background: tomato;
display: flex;
width: 50%;
height: 250px;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700|Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Esperanza G. Perlado Website</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- HEADER -->

<header class="header">
<h1 class="header-logo">Esperanza G. Perlado Website<a href="#"></a></h1>
    <div class="header-container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">PINTURA</a></li>
                <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">DIBUJO</a></li>
                <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">OBRA GRÁFICA</a></li>
                <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">OBRAS</a></li>
                <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">SOBRE MÍ</a></li>
                <li class="header-menu-item" id="item-lang-es"><a href="#">ES</a></li>
                <li class="header-menu-item" id="item-lang-en"><a href="#">EN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>




    <section class="header-section">
            <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#"></a>
            <span>Serie 4 estaciones</span>
            <h1>primavera</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, explicabo pariatur nemo necessitatibus eveniet saepe distinctio esse laborum neque voluptatum quia? Praesentium ea, ipsa laborum ad eligendi tempora recusandae esse.</p>
            <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
        </section>




</header>

<!-- MAIN -->

<main class="main">
   

<section class="slider">
    
    <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
    <h1>verano</h1>
</section>

<section>
        <img 
        <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
        <h1>invierno</h1>
    </section>

<section>
    <img src="#" alt="#">
    <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
    <h1>calle vacia</h1>
</section>    

<section>
    <img src="" alt="">
</section>

<section>
    <span>dias de la semana</span>
    <h1>paseo del domingo</h1>
    <!-- LINEA EN CSS -->
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
</section>

<section>
    <img src="#" alt="#">
</section>

<section>
    <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
    <h1>deducción</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</section>

<section>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h1>mis obras</h1>
            <p>conoce todas las obras</p>
            <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1>venta</h1>
            <p>compra la que mas te guste</p>
            <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div> 
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1>contribuye</h1>
            <p>todas las donaciones se recaudan para fines beneficos</p>
            <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
</main>

<!-- FOOTER -->

<footer>
<span>Todos los derechos reservados</span>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Gracias!!

Comment: amigo podrías pasar todo tu código para ayudarte

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con las cajas? ¿A los elementos LI?

Comment: No me refiero al H1, al div y al section. Al meter dentro del head el último section me lo alinea en línea y quiero que aparezca debajo.

Answer (score 0):

Según tengo entendido quieres colocar tu `h1`, `<div class="header-container">` en línea y tu `<section class="header-section">` gusto debajo, sin que se alinea.

Para ello podrías usar `flex-wrap`, para mostrar los elementos en varias filas.

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  /* La propiedad flex-wrap define si, y cómo, el contenedor quiere que sus hijos se envuelvan. */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;     
}
```

También existe `flex-direction` con el valor `colum`, es decir, para apilar los elementos en una columna de arriba a abajo.

```
.header {
  display: flex;
  /* Use el valor de la columna para apilar los elementos en una columna de arriba a abajo. */
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;     
}
```

**Un posible ejemplo:**

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* reglas generales */

a {
  color: inherit;
  /* ambos heredan del hereda del padre */
  text-decoration: inherit;
}


/* reglas tipograficas por defecto */

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.45;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #333;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: steelblue;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* IMAGENES  */

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Responsivo */
}


/* BACKGROUND */

html {
  background: url('img/fondo-dark.png');
}

body {
  max-width: 93.75rem;
  /* ANCHO CENTRAL */
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}


/* HEADER *******************************************************************************************************************************************
*/

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* La propiedad flex-wrap define si, y cómo, el contenedor quiere que sus hijos se envuelvan. */
  align-items: center;
  /* La propiedad align-items alinea los elementos verticalmente. */
  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  background: url('img/dibujos/mujer-1600-1200-min.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.header-logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  background: url('desarrollo/logo.svg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.logo a {
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
}

.header-container {
  width: 75%;
  /*Con este valor puedes ir jugando. */
  height: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 1rem 1rem;
}

.header li {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#item-lang-es {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 0;
}

#item-lang-en {
  padding-left: 0rem;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.header-menu-item {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.header-section {
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Espacios entre cajas. */

.header-section div {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700|Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Esperanza G. Perlado Website</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- HEADER -->

  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="header-logo">Esperanza G. Perlado Website
      <a href="#"></a>
    </h1>
    <div class="header-container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">PINTURA</a></li>
          <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">DIBUJO</a></li>
          <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">OBRA GRÁFICA</a></li>
          <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">OBRAS</a></li>
          <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">SOBRE MÍ</a></li>
          <li class="header-menu-item" id="item-lang-es"><a href="#">ES</a></li>
          <li class="header-menu-item" id="item-lang-en"><a href="#">EN</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <section class="header-section">
      <div>
        <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#"></a>
        <span>Serie 4 estaciones</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1>primavera</h1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, explicabo pariatur nemo necessitatibus eveniet saepe distinctio esse laborum neque voluptatum quia? Praesentium ea, ipsa laborum ad eligendi tempora recusandae esse.</p>
      </div>

      <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>

    </section>

  </header>

  <!-- MAIN -->

  <main class="main">


    <section class="slider">

      <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
      <h1>verano</h1>
    </section>

    <section>
      <img src="#" alt="#">
      <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
      <h1>invierno</h1>
    </section>

    <section>
      <img src="#" alt="#">
      <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
      <h1>calle vacia</h1>
    </section>

    <section>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </section>

    <section>
      <span>dias de la semana</span>
      <h1>paseo del domingo</h1>
      <!-- LINEA EN CSS -->
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <img src="#" alt="#">
    </section>

    <section>
      <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
      <h1>deducción</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </section>

    <section>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h1>mis obras</h1>
          <p>conoce todas las obras</p>
          <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h1>venta</h1>
          <p>compra la que mas te guste</p>
          <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h1>contribuye</h1>
          <p>todas las donaciones se recaudan para fines beneficos</p>
          <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </main>

  <!-- FOOTER -->

  <footer>
    <span>Todos los derechos reservados</span>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Ahora si quieres que los tres elementos queden uno debajo de otro te dejo una alternativa usando `flex-direction`.

**Un ejemplo alternativo:**

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}


/* reglas generales */

a {
  color: inherit;
  /* ambos heredan del hereda del padre */
  text-decoration: inherit;
}


/* reglas tipograficas por defecto */

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.45;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #333;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: steelblue;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* IMAGENES  */

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Responsivo */
}


/* BACKGROUND */

html {
  background: url('img/fondo-dark.png');
}

body {
  max-width: 93.75rem;
  /* ANCHO CENTRAL */
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
}


/* HEADER *******************************************************************************************************************************************
*/

.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Con el valor colum logras apilar los elementos en una columna de arriba a abajo. */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: url('img/dibujos/mujer-1600-1200-min.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.header-logo {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: url('desarrollo/logo.svg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.logo a {
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
}

.header-container {
  width: 95%;
  height: 5rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin: 1rem 1rem;
}

.header li {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif, Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#item-lang-es {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 0;
}

#item-lang-en {
  padding-left: 0rem;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.header-menu-item {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.header-section {
  background: tomato;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/* Espacios entre cajas. */

.header-section div {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700|Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Esperanza G. Perlado Website</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- HEADER -->

  <header class="header">
    <h1 class="header-logo">Esperanza G. Perlado Website
      <a href="#"></a>
    </h1>
    <div class="header-container">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">PINTURA</a></li>
          <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">DIBUJO</a></li>
          <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">OBRA GRÁFICA</a></li>
          <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">OBRAS</a></li>
          <li class="header-menu-item"><a href="#">SOBRE MÍ</a></li>
          <li class="header-menu-item" id="item-lang-es"><a href="#">ES</a></li>
          <li class="header-menu-item" id="item-lang-en"><a href="#">EN</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <section class="header-section">
      <div>
        <a href="#"><img src="#" alt="#"></a>
        <span>Serie 4 estaciones</span>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h1>primavera</h1>
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias, explicabo pariatur nemo necessitatibus eveniet saepe distinctio esse laborum neque voluptatum quia? Praesentium ea, ipsa laborum ad eligendi tempora recusandae esse.</p>
      </div>

      <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>

    </section>

  </header>

  <!-- MAIN -->

  <main class="main">


    <section class="slider">

      <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
      <h1>verano</h1>
    </section>

    <section>
      <img src="#" alt="#">
      <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
      <h1>invierno</h1>
    </section>

    <section>
      <img src="#" alt="#">
      <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
      <h1>calle vacia</h1>
    </section>

    <section>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </section>

    <section>
      <span>dias de la semana</span>
      <h1>paseo del domingo</h1>
      <!-- LINEA EN CSS -->
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <img src="#" alt="#">
    </section>

    <section>
      <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
      <h1>deducción</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    </section>

    <section>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h1>mis obras</h1>
          <p>conoce todas las obras</p>
          <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h1>venta</h1>
          <p>compra la que mas te guste</p>
          <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h1>contribuye</h1>
          <p>todas las donaciones se recaudan para fines beneficos</p>
          <div><a href="#">Más información</a></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </main>

  <!-- FOOTER -->

  <footer>
    <span>Todos los derechos reservados</span>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

*Tutoriales útiles:*

- *w3schools* [flex:wrap](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp#flex-wrap) y [flex-direction](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp#flex-direction).
- Unos trucos muy buenos usando `flex` [A Complete Guide to
  Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).